# Excel - Locating cell contents based around ROW() and COLUMN()

Tags: function, excel-formula

I'm trying to use a cells fixed position to then reference cells around it.

In pseudo code I'm after something like:

```
=CELL("contents",COLUMN()-1 ROW())
```

So it will get the value of the cell to it's left and display it in this cell.

The reason I am doing it this way it to be able to blanket paste across a number of cells and it will work out which cells info to display automatically.

Is there a way of using a modified `COLUMN()` and `ROW()` in place of the [reference] value on the `CELL()` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=Offset()` for this.

```
=Offset(contents, 0, -1)
```

Assuming that "Contents" is a named range. If it's not then just reference the cell

```
=Offset(B4, 0, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`=OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address")),3,6)`

This will return contents of a cell that is 3 rows down and 6 columns to the right from the current one.